# Spring custom validation cascade (on nested objects)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got two classes: Case and Protocol.

Case contains List of Protocols, and there is a custom validation logic for both of it.

Case object arrives to Controller as @RequestBody. I'd like to invoke CaseValidator on Case object and ProtocolValidator on each nested Protocols objects automatically.

I've already tried to add both validators, but this works only for Case validation:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initCaseBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(caseValidator);
}

@InitBinder
protected void initProtocolBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(protocolValidator);
}
```

Is there a way?

Thank you.